# Help! A moderator asked me to undelete my "answer", but it seems I can't

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-answers, undelete

Most users might not be able to see my deleted answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318713/405046), to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200352/is-there-a-different-standard-for-christianity-se).

My answer (linked above) was one of my first on SE, I was new, it really needed improvement. One of the new moderators deleted it and left a very useful comment, inviting me to fix it. I truly am thankful to the moderator for this because I learned so much, honestly.

The moderator specifically commented that he welcomed me fixing my "answer", then asked me to flag it to be undeleted. BUT, when I flag it for undelete, I get a system message that it *cannot be undeleted because it was deleted by a moderator*. I don't know how to contact him or any other way to follow his request to have my "answer" undeleted.

Can someone please either:

1. Tell me where/how to follow the moderator's request to have it undeleted or
2. Contact a moderator to have my answer reviewed for undelete, as the moderator requested.

Comment: I added the actual request to the title, if I got it wrong please roll back and clarify.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the "answer" that got us into this discussion originally suggested adding the "status-completed" tag, but that and other "status-" tags are only for actual changes in the SE software and would not apply here. "bug" was added because it was a requirement, but "support" seems better, so I accept that edit. But, to "clarify", if I change the title into a feature request, that would somewhat misrepresent the original situation. So, I'm creating a proper "feature-request" discussion because I think that the current work flow genuinely has some "UX philosophy" concerns. Link next...

Comment: Here is the feature request I posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320990/should-an-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator-have-a-different-informative-cant-unde

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *voted* to undelete, you didn't *flag* to undelete. Pressing the "undelete" button is voting to undelete your answer. You need to use the flag dialog and submit a custom moderator flag to ask for it to be undeleted. A moderator will then review it and undelete if necessary.

Comment: That did it! Should this change to a UX request or feature request? Maybe at least the message should include your instructions?

Comment: ...and, it's already been undeleted. So awesome. The problem again was that *I needed to learn something*.

Comment: Well, I've used that mod message or varients of it for years. It's probably totally on me to make it clearer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I just wanna' say you're an awesome mod and the word "flag" should have been enough for me to see. And, really, thanks for this. I was better in other areas of the site because your delete really forced me to think hard and become better.

Comment: And that's the real point of a deletion. But yeah, I've been here a long time - which sometimes leaves me blind of what a newer user might face. So if there's room for making it clearer, feel free to feedback

Answer (score 13):

You should flag it as “in need of moderator intervention” and ask for undeletion. This will alert some moderator to undelete your answer. Regular users can’t undelete things deleted by moderators so that’s the flag they wanted you to use. Also there is no such thing as an “undelete flag”, only undelete votes.

Comment: Upvoting because your answer really provides more background info to explain what is going on. Initially, about a month ago, I thought I needed more rep to do this. You cleared that up.